# Django field ends up blank after save() AND code that prevents it from reverting to a blank value

Tags: python, django, postgresql, debugging

A POST request hits one of my django GenericViewSet endpoint that find a matching instance and sets a value on it:

```
obj = models.CarObj.objects.get(id=self.request.data['id'])
if self.request.data.get('field_value',False):
    obj.field = self.request.data['field_value']
    obj.save()
```

this works like 95% of the time but occasionally I will catch an obj that has a blank `field` value after I KNOW that end point was hit correctly. So I changed my code to this:

```
obj = models.CarObj.objects.get(id=self.request.data['id'])
if self.request.data.get('field_value',False):
    obj.field = self.request.data['field_value']
    obj.save()
    obj2 = models.CarObj.objects.get(id=obj.id)
    print("Mem: {} | DB: {}".format(obj.field, obj2.field))
    if obj2.field == '' or len(obj2.field) == 0:
        raise ValueError("Mem does not match DB")
```

The print always shows the same CORRECT values between the memory instance and the newest fetch from the DB. The ValueError is never raised. Yet sometimes `field` is still blank.

So I went through the ModelViewSet of `CarObj` and made sure all the POST/ PATCH/ PUT all have:
`self.request.data.pop('field_value')` before their respective `serializers` are populated with the `self.request.data`. Yet sometimes `field` is still blank.

I have added a `pre_save` signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=models.CarObj)
def carobj_pre_save(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    if 'field' in instance.get_dirty_fields(check_relationship=True):
        field_new_value = getattr(instance,'field','')
        if field_new_value == '' or len(field_new_value) == 0:
            try:
                old_instance = models.CarObj.objects.get(id=instance.id)
                setattr(instance, 'field', getattr(old_instance, 'field', ''))
            except models.CarObj.DoesNotExist:
                pass
```

Which should in theory should stop the DB value from being set to a blank value. And what happens? The print says `Mem` and `DB` both have the same correct value. `ValueError` is not raised. But the `field` is still sometimes blank.

WTF.

Comment: What does the Postgres show when you do the save?

Comment: Also I don't think `getattr(instance,'field','')` is doing what you think it is.  It can return `None` if the field value is `NULL` and you don't test for that.

Comment: After the Save(), if a run a raw select in python after the save, shows the same thing the prints show. The field value due to dub constraints can never be None/ NULL

Comment: My previous comment was missing a word, it should have been: What does the Postgres log show when you do the save? In other words what is actually hitting the database?

Comment: Not something I can see as due to security reasons on a production setup at my work.

Comment: Then you are up a creek without a paddle. I would say it is a bigger security concern not knowing what your code is actually doing the data.